# Rename files with one line command

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-rename

I have this directory, and want to rename the files:

```
===> ls -1 Der-vierte-Weise/
10 - 10 - Erkenntniss.ogg
1 - 01 - Hoffnung.ogg
11 - 11 - Wahrheit.ogg
12 - 12 - Dankbarkeit.ogg
13 - 13 - Kredits.ogg
2 - 02 - Familie.ogg
3 - 03 - Demut.ogg
4 - 04 - Freude.ogg
5 - 05 - Schoenheit.ogg
6 - 06 - Solidaritaet.ogg
7 - 07 - Entscheidung.ogg
8 - 08 - Hilfe.ogg
9 - 09 - Unterstuetzung.ogg
```

The result should look like this:

```
===> ls -1 Der-vierte-Weise/
01 - Hoffnung.ogg
02 - Familie.ogg
...
```

I would like to solve this with common shell tools.

Comment: *I would like to solve this with common shell tools.* I'm not saying that you don't have a good reason, but I trust you've asked and answered a question to yourself "why?". Last time I had a very similar problem to solve I immediately shoved Bash to one side and solved it in Python. So much easier (but I did already know Python, string methods, glob.glob and os.rename -- and I also had to recurse down a tree full of foldernames with spaces and other awkward characters, none of which are a cause of extra bother if using Python)

Comment: @nigel222 I am lazy and I want to type as less characters as possible. That's why I don't want to use python here. Don't get me wrong. Up to now Python is my preferred programming language and use it daily.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `rename`...

```
rename -n 's/^[0-9]+ - //' *
```

Remove `-n` after testing to actually rename the files

#### Explanation

- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `^` start of string
- `[0-9]+` some numbers

Comment: what kind of regex flower is supported by the `rename` tool. Does it use PCRE? ... would be great.

Comment: @guettli strictly speaking, no it isn't PCRE (that's Perl *Compatible* Regular Expressions). The `rename` is a Perl script so it has full Perl regular expression support; PCRE is only a subset of that. However, anything you know from PCRE will be applicable to `rename`.

Comment: @terdon I don't care for the implementation. If you look at it with math-glasses, then `rename` has perl compatible regular expressions. Yes, the pcre implementation does not get used. I understood this :-) Thank you for your fast reply.

Answer (score 9):

`bash` parameter expansion to strip off the required portion from start:

```
for f in *[[:blank:]]*.ogg; do echo mv -i -- "$f" "${f#[[:digit:]]*-[[:blank:]]}"; done
```

Expanded form:

```
for f in *[[:blank:]]*.ogg; do 
    echo mv -i -- "$f" "${f#[[:digit:]]*-[[:blank:]]}"
done
```

`echo` is for dry-running; get rid of it for actual action:

```
for f in *[[:blank:]]*.ogg; do mv -i -- "$f" "${f#[[:digit:]]*-[[:blank:]]}"; done
```

**Example:**

```
% ls -1
1 - 01 - Hoffnung.ogg
2 - 02 - Familie.ogg

% for f in *[[:blank:]]*.ogg; do mv -i -- "$f" "${f#[[:digit:]]*-[[:blank:]]}"; done 

% ls -1                                                                             
01 - Hoffnung.ogg
02 - Familie.ogg
```

Comment: Yes, works. Thank you. Since I know perl compatible regular expression from Python (which I use daily), I prefer the `rename` command. (Less typing needed).

Comment: @guettli `rename` is the way to go if you are familiar with PCRE; the `rename` answer was already given so have to move with pure `bash`. Just to note, `python`'s `re` (or `regex`) module is not fully PCRE compatible BTW.

Comment: @guettli Also did you just downvoted my answer? :O

Comment: Yes I did, and I upvoted your comment. I hope you don't take it personally. Don't get me wrong, but my personal opinion is that this `${f#[[:digit:]]*-[[:blank:]]}` is ugly. Yes it works. But we live in the 21century. I think it is time to switch from "it works" to "it's easy and fun". If "it works" is the goal, then linux will never loose the prejudice of not being user friendly. Since you already got a lot of up-votes, this one down-vote should not hurt (I hope). If it does, tell me, and I will take it back.

Comment: @guettli It's fine. How about `${f#[0-9]*- }`? Looking good on your eyes?

Comment: at school I like math and physics, and disliked foreign languages. It's the same here. I know how to speak one language for this (perl compatible regular expressions). I have no interest in learning a different flavor. I know that other people feel different. They know the regexs which are used in gnu shell tools. Maybe they don't want to learn pcre. That's ok. In other word: I am lazy ... But I am willing to learn. Can you please show me the reference of this syntax?

Comment: @guettli Whatever suits you. Here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html Just to note, the character class `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:blank:]]` were there to comply with your `locale`, these are pretty common in Regex too.