# Where does the `rename` command come from?

Tags: command-line, dpkg, rename

Where does the `rename` command come from?

```
user@host> dpkg -S /usr/bin/rename
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/rename
```

Comment: The `rename` that ships with Fedora is a different one, though. It seems to be a compiled program and it is not nearly as powerful as the `rename` that ships with Ubuntu. So be careful when you use scripts on a different Linux distribution.

Comment: @MartinUeding can you please leave a comment here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/873661/rename-files-with-one-line-command

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/58618/582017) says it's [`prename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/prename.1.html)

Answer (score 20):

Surprisingly, it comes from the `rename` package.

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/rename
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 окт 17  2013 /usr/bin/rename -> /etc/alternatives/rename
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/rename
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 апр 29  2016 /etc/alternatives/rename -> /usr/bin/file-rename
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/file-rename
rename: /usr/bin/file-rename
```

Comment: Why does `dpkg -S` not follow the symlink? Bug or feature?

Comment: @guettli [feature](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html): "This  command  will  not  list extra files created by maintainer scripts, nor will it list alternatives."

Comment: @muru why does dpkg not list alternatives? I don't understand it.

Comment: The symlink does not belong to the package itself.

Comment: @guettli because it's not `dpkg`'s job. `dpkg` only deals with installed packages.  Use `update-alternatives --query rename `, it will show you the resolved link path

Comment: If a new comer asks a debian/ubuntu expert: "How can I find the matching package for command foo", the expert will say "dpkg -S foo".  Who's job is the overall user experience?

Comment: @guettli certainly not mine, nor Pilot6's nor Serg's. You can make it yours and file a feature request.

Comment: @guettli See [Debian Bug #198220](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=198220). It would be handy if `dpkg`/`dpkg-query` offered this info conveniently. However,  I don't think `dpkg -S` should *silently* dereference symlinks until it finds a package file. `dpkg -S foo` isn't supposed to find the command `foo`, it finds the the package that installed the *file* `foo`, and is most useful when invoked with a file's absolute path. It'd be nice if `dpkg -S /usr/bin/rename` explained why no package provides that symlink, but I think it should still tell the truth that no package does.

Comment: @EliahKagan thank you for providing the relevant bug in debians ticket systems. Is there a way to push this (without coding)? Is there a way to vote or donate for bugs?

Answer (score 12):

You will probably find that it's a symbolic link that is managed by the `update-alternatives` mechanism:

```
$ ls -l $(which rename)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jun 29  2016 /usr/bin/rename -> /etc/alternatives/rename
```

You can see the optional implementations using

```
$ update-alternatives --list rename
/usr/bin/file-rename
/usr/bin/prename
```

and can choose between implementations using

```
update-alternatives --config rename
```

FWIW `file-rename` is provided by the `rename` package, whereas the original `prename` is provided by `perl` itself. From `apt-cache show rename`:

> This package provides both a perl interface for renaming files 
>   (File::Rename) and a command line tool 'rename' which is intended to 
>   replace the version currently supplied by the perl package.

As if this was not already confusing enough, you may also come across yet another `rename` from the `util-linux` package - see [What's with all the renames?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames)

Comment: Why isn't rename.ul available as a rename alternative?

Comment: @Random832 For command-line utilities, alternatives are supposed to be syntax-compatible replacements for each other (at least for some common core of functionality); rename.ul and prename do not qualify.

Answer (score 7):

If we're talking about `/usr/bin/rename`, which is a pretty nifty perl script, then `rename` command belongs to its own separate package.

```
rename:
  Installed: 0.20-4
  Candidate: 0.20-4
  Version table:
 *** 0.20-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In case of Korn shell and its derivatives, `rename` is a shell built-in command.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/mksh

$ type rename
rename is a shell builtin
```

Comment: Why "If we're talking about /usr/bin/rename"? The question contains the absolute path.

Comment: @guettli  The question asks about `rename` command, yet `rename` isn't only referred to `/usr/bin/rename` , as you see in my answer. Users who have ksh or mksh shells might not be aware of that.  When I personally started with `mksh` , I was very baffled when `rename` wasn't accepting the regular expression, until I realized those were two different things.  Also, don't take my words "If we're talking about x" literally, consider it as a way of saying "In case of "